# Oracle and DateTime math

Tags: oracle

I'm writing a query to select some records. I have this data:

```
Event Table
------------------
Definition
    EVE_RID         NUMBER(10)
    EVE_START_DATE  Date

Data:
    EVE_RID     EVE_START_DATE
    156891      11/1/2016

Agenda Table
------------------
Definition:
    AGD_EVE_RID     NUMBER(10)
    AGD_DAY         NUMBER(2)
    AGD_START_TIME  NUMBER(4)

Data:
AGD_EVE_RID     AGD_DAY     AGD_START_TIME
156891          1           1000     
156891          1           1400     
156891          8           1000     
156891          8           1400     
156891          15          1000     
156891          15          1400     

WAList Table
------------------
Definition:
    WAL_STARTTIME   DATE
    WAL_KEY         VARCHAR2(50)

Data:
WAL_STARTTIME           WAL_KEY                
11/1/2016 10:00:00 AM   6341371019318098180
11/1/2016 2:00:00 PM    7561779448126279684
11/8/2016 10:00:00 AM   6904435321948802820
11/8/2016 2:00:00 PM    7998296559469684996
11/15/2016 10:00:00 AM  4690144247933554180
11/15/2016 2:00:00 PM   7931460546152111876
```

What I need is some way to match records from the WAList table from the Agenda table.
How could I write my where clause to match the WALList records to the Agenda.AGD_DAY records and return the correct Key for the correct day? This would be result:

```
EVE_START_DATE   AGD_DAY    AGD_START_TIME  WAL_KEY                
11/1/2016       1           1000            6341371019318098180
11/1/2016       1           1400            7561779448126279684
11/1/2016       8           1000            6904435321948802820
11/1/2016       8           1400            7998296559469684996
11/1/2016       15          1000            4690144247933554180
11/1/2016       15          1400            7931460546152111876
```

Comment: Should it *just* be based on time as I can see in your expected output date is always `11/1/2016`?

Comment: But look at the StartTime in the WAL table. It has the Sessions.StartDate + SessionDay + the StartTime (in 12 hr format)

Comment: What are your data types?  Are `StartDate` in the first table and `StartTime` in the second both `date` data types?  If so, is the time component of `StartDate` always midnight?  If so, why would you have a `date` and a separate `StartTime` column in the first table that is a `varchar2` (I'm guessing) rather than just storing the time correctly in `StartDate`?

Comment: What are the datatypes in the tables? Just describe table and post here?

Comment: @JustinCave, It's because these tables were designed by different people at different times. You can't say that you have never run across anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming datatypes as —
Sessions.startdate as varchar2 and WAL.startTime as date:

```
select s.startdate, s.sessionDay, s.startTime, w.key 
from sessions s join WAL w
on to_date(to_char(to_date(s.startdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy') + s.sessionDay, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
||s.starttime,'mm/dd/yyyyhh24mi') = w.startTime;
```

Comment: That's pretty close to what I need.

Comment: But this code returns a **a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected** .... `to_date((e.eve_start_date + a.agd_day) || ' ' || substr(a.agd_start_time,1,2) || ':' || substr(a.agd_start_time,3,2), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24mi'),`

Comment: While this solution had issues for me, it led to the solution.